# How to develop a simple UI designer using dojo?

Tags: user-interface, dojo, editor

I want to build simple UI designer using dojo, but need some guidance/suggestions on where should I start.

Basically what I want to do is:

I have some predefined UI components(some dijits) which can be put into a page canvas. The page can be pre-layout as two columns or three columns. Users can pick one dijit and place it into the page. He can move the dijits, resize it by dragging a handler and can also place it to other places in the page.

So as a summary, I need to develop two things:
1) a UI palette, where users can view all available dijits. And drag one and drop it into the page.
2) a page canvas, where dijits can be put into. And user can move dijits around the page or resize them.

I need some suggestions on where should I start, and what functions I can leverage from dojo or some helpful open-source projects.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at the open source Maqetta project, which is a WYSIWYG editor to build dojo UI.
It's available here:

http://maqetta.org/

The source code is available in case you want to know more about how it works.

Comment: thanks, Patrick. Yes, I did look into maqetta. It is a promising tool. But I don't want to use all of the fancy features provided by maqetta. That's why I am looking to see whether I can create a simple one myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar with a graphical workflow editor.  Statuses on the left which could be dragged to and dropped onto a canvas.  User could manipulate them, etc.

Here are my suggestions:

Use a Store to hold all the data that represents the form layout.

- you should document a data model that will be used.
- this is the data you send back to the server.
- instantiate widgets based on the data in the store.
- when a user modifies the data, update the store.
- use the Observable pattern to be notified when data changes in the store, and update the  widgets

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store.html

Utilize the drag and drop functionality of Dojo.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/dnd.html

I would try to avoid dojo/gfx (SVG) if you can.  It will add a lot of complexity.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/gfx.html#dojox-gfx

You could investigate the Dojox MVC code.  I have not looked at this code so I have no opinion.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mvc.html#dojox-mvc

Comment: thanks for answering this. I believe I still need some time to catch up on this.